# Reading a file in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am trying to read content from file in blackberry and i read the file content to result object and when i am trying to print the result object it gives error and the file is in res folder,and this is code that i got problem

```
private String readTextFile(String fName) {
  String result = null;
  FileConnection fconn = null;
  DataInputStream is = null;
  try {
   fconn = (FileConnection) Connector.open(fName, Connector.READ_WRITE);
   is = fconn.openDataInputStream();
   byte[] data = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);
   result = new String(data);
   System.out.println("result data is ...... "+result);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  } finally {
   try {
    if (null != is)

     is.close();
    if (null != fconn)
     fconn.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   }
  }
  return result;
 }
```

Comment: it doesnt read content in the file and gives source not found error

Comment: I can't help you with Blackberry questions, but those who can would probably appreciate *a little more detail*

Answer (score 0):

what is fName here ?

The file name or the path could cause similar problem.